# Override output assembly instruction in clang or gcc

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, clang

I would like to know if there is an easy way to indicate `clang` or `gcc` to override a specific instruction when generating the assembly code. For example forcing the compiler to use

`mov eax,0`

instead of

`xor eax, eax`

If that cannot be done easily where should I look at the code to implement that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no easy way. Since this is a simple optimization, I guess it shouldn't be too hard to find in the compiler source. Seems to be in `i386.md`, the `mov_xor` pattern.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Hi @Jester. which file do you mean? https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc

Comment: @fuz curiosity about modifying compilers, understand how they work...

Comment: [gcc/config/i386/i386.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/master/gcc/config/i386/i386.md)

Comment: You would have to modify the compiler.

Comment: what about using LLVM passes? http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html

Comment: Yes, for Clang you can write a pass that would perform transformation you want.

Comment: @arrowd I've tried that and I get the instructions at the llvm bytecode level but not at the native x86 level to modify it. How can I do so? I've used this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/llvm-dev/UC5BPevr_hE

Comment: Ah, I thought you are talking about inline assembly. Then look at machine passes.